# Why is my first .nextline in the loop skipped then not skipped the next time around? and how do I stop it from overwriting?

Tags: java, loops, text, while-loop, filewriter

I needed to create a basic program to input text to a .txt document so I created this but I don't see why the first question is skipped when the program is first run.

It doesn't happen if the first question that sets the loop isn't there. Also how do I stop it from overwriting what is already there in the txt document when all I want it to do is add to it.

So far the last method seems to work far but I thought I would still include it.

```
package productfile;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Mp
 */
public class Products {

public void inputDetails(){
int i=0;
int count=0;
String name;
String description;
String price;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many products would you like to enter?");
count = sc.nextInt();

do{
    try{

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c:/Users/Mp/test.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (fw);

        System.out.println("Please enter the product name.");
        name = sc.nextLine(); 
        pw.println("Product name: " + name );

        System.out.println("Please enter the product description.");
        description = sc.nextLine();
        pw.println("Product description: " + description );

        System.out.println("Please enter the product price.");
        price = sc.nextLine();
        pw.println("Product price: " + price );

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

        i++;

  }catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("We have had an input/output error:");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    } while (i<count);
}

public void display(){
    String textLine;
try{

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:/Users/Mp/test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        do{
            textLine = br.readLine();
            if (textLine == null){
               return;
            } else {
                System.out.println(textLine);
            }
        } while (textLine != null);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("We have had an input/output error:");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are inputting the `int` for `nextInt()` you are also pressing enter for the input to be received, which translates into a new line being also read. This new line is considered input for your next call to `nextLine()`. You will need to put an artificial `nextLine()` after the call to `nextInt()` or use `nextLine()` directly and parse the input as an `int`:

```
count = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
```

or

```
count = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

.nextInt() does not catch your Enter press. You'll need to put a blank .nextLine() after it.